# Linear constraint formulation (OR-statement)

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, constraint

I have the decision variable $X_{iz}$

And I have two parameters $T_i\in\{0,1\}$ and $IT_z\in\{0,1,2\}$. I can only assign $i$ to $z$ if the following holds:

- for $T_i=0$, $IT_z$ needs to be $0$ or $2$
- for $T_i=1$, $IT_z$ needs to be $1$ or $2$
- So for every value of $T_i$, a value of $2$ for $IT_z$ must satisfy the constraint
- Or $T_i$ needs to be equal to $IT_z$

I cannot seem to figure out how to make a valid constraint for this problem, any tips?

Comment: Do you have 2 $T$ and 3 $IT$ or do you have one $T$ and one $IT$ where $T$ can be $\{0, 1\}$ and $IT$ can be $\{0, 1, 2\}$. If the latter, then you don't need the indices. Just say $T \in \{0,1\}$ and $IT \in \{0,1,2\}$

Comment: No I have multiple $i$'s and multiple $z$'s, each has their own value of $T\in\{0,1\}$ and $IT\in\{0,1,2\}$.

Comment: Check this answer from [Decision Variable Value from a Set](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/2660/36)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the new problem description, it seems like you just want to fix $X_{i,z}=0$ for some disallowed $(i,z)$ pairs. An even better approach is to avoid defining $X_{i,z}$ in those cases.

Answer (score 2):

Introduce a new binary variable $z_i$ and linear constraints:
\begin{align}
-z_i \le \text{IT}_i - \text{T}_i &\le 2 z_i \\
\text{IT}_i &\ge 2 z_i
\end{align}
If $z_i=0$ then $\text{IT}_i = \text{T}_i$. If $z_i=1$ then $\text{IT}_i \ge 2$, hence $=2$.

Comment: I think this is not correct, because when $T_i=0$ and $IT_i=1$ the constraint also satisfies. And this should not be the case. That is what I am struggling with.

Comment: Sorry, I misread $0$ or $2$ as $0$ to $2$.

Comment: Corrected just now.

Comment: Note: all your indices are of type $i$, but actually $IT$ has index $z$. Is the $z$ (you introduced) of type $i$ or of type $z$? I tried some things now, but the model seems infeasible

Comment: Hmm, you changed the question after I posted my answer, and I don't quite understand the new question.  My binary variable $z_i$ has nothing to do with your new index $z$.  Is $X_{i,z}$ a binary decision variable?  Are $\text{T}_i$ and $\text{IT}_{z}$ now decision variables or constants?

Comment: $X_{i,z}$ is a binary decision variable and $IT_z$ and $T_i$ are constants. I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101380/discussion-between-harry-van-t-kamp-and-rob-pratt).

Comment: Was this meant as an alternative to the other [answer](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/3089/491)?

Comment: No, it was the first answer, which answered the original problem that has now been lost.